# Referencing TabControls from another Form C++/CLI

Tags: c++, winforms, reference, c++-cli

I am trying to convert this tabbed browser into C++ from visual basic.
I am trying to reference the Tab Control from Form1.h. 
Here is the code on Form1.h:

```
    private: System::Void Form1_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             String^ title = String::Concat("TabPage ",(tabControl1->TabCount + 1).ToString());
             tab^ newtab = gcnew tab;
             newtab->Show();
             newtab->TopLevel = false;
             newtab->Dock = System::Windows::Forms::DockStyle::Fill;
             TabPage^ myTabPage = gcnew TabPage(title);
             myTabPage->Controls->Add(newtab);
             tabControl1->TabPages->Add(myTabPage);

         }
```

The code on the second form that is trying to create another tab is this:

```
private: System::Void newTabToolStripMenuItem_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

         tab^ newtab = gcnew tab;
         newtab->Show();
         newtab->TopLevel = false;
         newtab->Dock = System::Windows::Forms::DockStyle::Fill;
         TabPage^ myTabPage = gcnew TabPage();
         myTabPage->Controls->Add(newtab);
         tabControl1->TabPages->Add(myTabPage);
     }
```

In visual basic all that is required is to add Form1. to the beginning like so...:

```
//Original
tabControl1.TabPages.Add(myTabPage);
//New
Form1.tabControl1.TabPages.Add(myTabPage);
```

How could I do this same thing in C++?

Comment: You should tag the question as "C++/CLI" and "Windows Forms" instead of just "C++", since this is not a C++ problem.

Comment: I would say you should grab documentation for TabPage at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabpage.aspx#Y0) and give yourself a try. Anyway extracting the task you want to be done from code is rather hard.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Basic provides a default instance of each class in your project. When you say `Form1.tabControl1`, you're actually getting a particular global instance of Form1, and accessing the tabControl1 field on that.

Add a way to send the instance of Form1 to the second form, and use that instead of `Form1`. Something simple like passing the instance of Form1 to the second form in its constructor will probably do the trick.